# How to edit environment variable for development and production?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, environment-variables

I want to deploy a React app + Node server on Heroku,

I saw that if you use create-react-app, you can use process.env.NODE_ENV to know if you're in development or in production, but I always get "development",  it doesn't work, so I tried this :

.env

```
REACT_APP_ENV=dev
```

In the React app, I tried to console log the variable, but it still at undefined

```
console.log("env ", process.env.REACT_APP_ENV); <-- output: undefined
```

But in the server, the console log is right,

```
if (process.env.REACT_APP_ENV === "prod") {
  app.use(express.static("build"));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve("build", "index.html")));
} else if (process.env.REACT_APP_ENV === "dev") {
  console.log("ENV ", process.env.REACT_APP_ENV); <-- output: "dev"
}
```

What is the easiest way to have a variable at "prod" when I'm in production, and at "dev" in development please ?

Thanks

Comment: Please check path of .env file ?

Comment: .env is at the root, I also have .env.development and .env.production beucase I tried this solution

Comment: can you share file of index,js where are you declare env file

Comment: https://github.com/Versifiction/ofilms/blob/master/src/App.js, i think there's a conflict between .env .env.developemnt and .env.production

Comment: The React app runs in the client, i.e a completely different context than the server so your env vars aren’t available there. If you’re using a bundler, like Webpack or Browserify, you can use that to inject env vars into the bundle. Otherwise, you’ll have to create an end-point that the client app can retrieve it from.

Comment: Please tell where write that  code  const dotenv   = require('dotenv').config();

Comment: it's in the server, here https://github.com/Versifiction/ofilms/blob/master/server.js

Comment: @Lennholm I need in the server and in the client to access to the same env variable, and I need to change it from "dev" to "prod" at the build... is it hard?

Comment: Are you also building your server app using a bundler? Or is it executed directly via Node?

Comment: i'm using creat-react-app, I think ot's using webpack in background @Gasim

Comment: Please see this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack

Comment: I see that you are using `.env.production` and `.env.development` in your repo (btw remove them from the repo). However, dotenv will not know which environment you are in. So, you should add `NODE_ENV=production` before your scripts if you want them to be in production mode. CRA does this automatically and it [cannot be overriden](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables). However, you need to add it to your Node app; so that it recognizes it.

Comment: yes I removed them but I had them because I need to change the endpoint of the axios requests (development: http://localhost:5000 and in production: http://ofilms.herokuapp.com), can we talk in the stackoverflow chat ? (I don't know how to do it)

Comment: I didn't mean that remove them from your files. `gitignore` them (but first remove and commit; then ignore). You should set these variables from your build system / platform. I see that you are using Heroku; so, [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) are the docs for it.

Answer (score 1):

From what you have written, my understanding is that you are trying to the same environmental variables as in `.env.development` and `.env.production`. Default path that `dotenv` package checks is `path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env')`; so, you need to change it:

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'; // if nothing is given, set it as development.
require("dotenv").config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, `.env.${env}`) });
// ^ do checks to make sure that random env vars are not written
```

Now, when you run your scripts, you need to run it by attaching the env vars to it:

```
NODE_ENV=development nodemon server.js
NODE_ENV=production nodemon server.js
```

As a result, dotenv will read `.env.development` and `.env.production`, respectively. CRA does this by default and [it is not overridable](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables):

```
npm start -> development
npm start -> production
```

There is nothing you can do about it (maybe eject but no need to do it). Just prepend the environmental variable in your scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "server:dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon server.js",
  "start": "concurrently \"npm run server:dev\" \"npm run client\"",
  "server:prod": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon server.js",
  ...
}
```

---

I would also like to mention that, this is something that might be useful in development environment to see how the production app is visible; however, in majority of scenarios, these variables should be set in the build / platform environment. For example, CI tool should set the env var as `production`; so that, you can see your website in the staging server. I would suggest you to only run the production script `server:prod` in dev environment and create another script that can be run universally without needing to manually show the env vars.

EDIT: Changed names of some scripts and added `development` fallback for env var.